# REPL not working on Mac OS

Tags: c#, python, macos, terminal

I am trying to use a REPL state in C# in my terminal. I am operating on in Mac OS. I tried using the popular REPL by entering csharp into the terminal. Alas, it tells me command not found. Any suggestions on what command I could use?

For a more elaborate example, if you type python into your terminal, you can then run your python interpreter in the terminal. I am looking for the C# equivalent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed a C# REPL (e.g. Mono)? C# is a Microsoft created language and not natively available on Mac.

Comment: I must have downloaded the wrong package at first. I deleted that package and reinstalled the Mono package, and it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
["ScriptCS"](http://scriptcs.net/) it has a Mono based port currently.  With .net core blooming in you should be able to see similar interfaces soon. [Monoport](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Building-on-Mac-and-Linux).  I have not tried it on OSX but works well on Windows.

Comment: I will give it a try now.